# VB.NET Show Current Playing Audio Waveform

Tags: vb.net, audio, waveform

I was wondering if its possible to make a program that shows the waveform of the current audio playing,like in FL Studio,without inserting an audio file.The sound that's playing no matter where,youtube,soundcloud etc...Does anyone know how to make it?

Comment: Waay too broad. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: BASS.NET library is low-level enough to allow you to do that.